# Retrieve last child from child node firebase realtime database swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my firebase realtime database

[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybpfj.png)

This is the snippet i am using its always returning nil

```
let rootRef = Database.database().reference()
            rootRef.child("POSTS").queryLimited(toLast: 1).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (myDataSnap) in
                let value = myDataSnap.value as? NSDictionary
                print(value as? Any)
            }
```

Comment: firstly change your DataSnapshot variable name to something else. Because DataSnapshot is a class in the firebase framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to access Id and Id's can be anything other than 0.
Than you can try the snippet below

```
let Key = rootRef.child("POSTS").childByAutoId().key
            rootRef.child("POSTS").child(Key!).setValue(postData.toDictionary()){
                (error:Error?, ref:DatabaseReference) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Data could not be saved: \(error).")
                } else {
                   //do stuff
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use .childAdded or childChanged instead of .value, this might solve it

```
let rootRef = Database.database().reference()
            rootRef.child("POSTS").queryLimited(toLast: 1).observeSingleEvent(of: .childChanged) { (myDataSnap) in
                let value = myDataSnap.value as? NSDictionary
                print(value as? Any)
            }
```

Comment: I am retreiving data on a button click

Comment: I need something instant.